# An analog of async.queue for Async/Await functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am modernizing some code. It has a piece to load database implemented as:

```
var customerQueue = async.queue(insertCustomer, DATABASE_PARALLELISM);
customerQueue.drain = function() {
    logger.info('all customers loaded');
    airportCodeMappingQueue.push(airportCodeMappings);
}
```

The function `insertCustomer` used to written with callbacks. I changed it to `async`/`await`, as a part of code modernization.

Now, think that I wrote an equivalent of async.queue as:

```
let customerQueueElements = [];
var customerQueue = {};
customerQueue.push = (customers) => {
  customers.forEach(customer => {
    customerQueueElements.push(insertCustomer(customer))
  });
}

const processQueue = async (queue, parallelism) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < queue.length; i += parallelism) {
    for (let j = 0; j < parallelism; j++) {
      let q = []
      if (queue[i + j]) {
        q.push(queue[i + j])
      }
      await Promise.all(q)
    }
  }
}
```

I am able now to do `await ProcessQueue(customerQueue, DATABASE_PARALLELISM)`, but the syntax is bad, and I am keeping a visible named variable for each queue.

What would be a good way to handling this?

Also, `drain()` should be hooked-up to `then`, right ?

Comment: The way you have written this will essentially run your `processQueue` *synchronously* even though it is doing it with `async` promises.  The `Promise.all(q)` will perform correctly but every iteration of the `for ()` will be halted until `Promise.all(q)` returns.  Is this what you are intending?

Comment: @Deryck *synchronously* != *sequentially*.

Comment: "*the syntax is bad, and I am keeping a visible named variable for each queue*" - you should be able to fix that by wrapping the whole thing in a (module factory) function that returns (exports) only the thing that you need to use the queue.

Comment: the context was just to grab his attention in case he thought the loop would proceed without delay as one might when taking old code and converting to new `async/await`.

Comment: JavaScript has only one thread. Hence, nothing runs truly in parallel. I believe that this thing, if I understand how `async.queue` works, will create the `parallelism` number of async requests, much like the original. Once, those are done, it will run this thing again.
Are you familiar with `async` package? Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi is correct, as far as direction. I put together a work-in-process version:

```
module.exports = function () {
  module.internalQueue = []
  module.func = undefined
  module.parallelism =  1

  const process = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < module.internalQueue.length; i += module.parallelism) {
      for (let j = 0; j < module.parallelism; j++) {
        let q = []
        if (module.internalQueue[i + j]) {
          q.push(module.func(module.internalQueue[i + j]))
        }
        await Promise.all(q)
      }
    }
    module.internalQueue = []
    module.drain()
  }

  module.queue = (func, parallelism = 1) => {
    module.func = func
    module.parallelism = parallelism
    return module
  }

  module.push = async (customers) => {
    module.internalQueue.push(customers)
    await process()
  }

  module.drain = () => {}

  return module
}
```

It is not exactly correct, yet. The signatures are similar to the `async` package, but my version shares the queue among all instances.

Need to figure out an easy way of creating an instance for each `function` with a separate e.g. "local" queue. Then, it will basically work like the original one.

Will update as I have progress.